# Create dictionary from values found in two other dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, compare

Issue:  I want to compare the two dictionaries - alist & blist - and use the values to create a new dictionary (clist).

****Please note that the alist is a result of comparing two other dicts****

The final solution would be:

clist = {'actual_url': ['bizname', 'buyer', 'date', 'Amount']

my attempt at doing this is below

Thanks for your help as I am really stuck!

```
alist = {acct_number': ['file_no', 'url', 'user', ['Biz_name', 'tool', 'date', 'amt']]}

blist = {acct_number: ['actual_case', 'actual_url']}

clist={}

for k, v in alist.item():
    for k, v in blist.item():
       if v==v:
          clist[v]:alist[v]
print(clist)
```

Comment: *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.*

Comment: Sure.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I want to take the values found in blist and create a new dictionary where the key becomes the actual_url (found in blist) and the values found in the a list becomes the values in the new dictionary.      This new dictionary would be called clist and it would look like this: clist = {accutal_url:['file_no', 'url', 'user', ['Biz_name', 'tool', 'date', 'amt']}

Comment: I want to take the values found in "blist" and create a new dictionary where the key becomes the "actual_url" (found in "blist" values) and the values found in the "alist" becomes the values in the new dictionary.      This new dictionary would be called "clist" and it would look like this: clist = {accutal_url:['file_no', 'url', 'user', ['Biz_name', 'tool', 'date', 'amt']

Comment: You should better edit the question instead of explaining what you want to do in the comments. Take a look at my answer and let me know if it works for you or if you need something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `'actual_url'` is always the second item in the list, you can do this:

```
clist = {}

clist[blist['acct_number'][1]] = alist['acct_number']
```

To iterate over multiple items in `alist`:

```
alist = {
    '12345': ['2', 'my_url.com', 'James', ['James corp', 'a', '100', '30']],
    '35299': ['5', 'another_url.org', 'Carrie', ['Carrie corp', 'b', '60', '20']],
    }

blist = {
    '12345': ['actual_case', 'my_url.com'],
    '35299': ['actual_case', 'another_url.org'],
    }

clist = {}

for acct_number, value in alist.items():
    clist[blist[acct_number][1]] = value
```